# File in Ubuntu equivalent to /etc/inittab file in RedHat

Tags: linux, ubuntu, init

What file in Ubuntu is equivalent to the `/etc/inittab` file in RedHat?

In RedHat the `/etc/inittab` file contains the settings related to the runlevel in which you want to boot Linux.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ubuntu uses Upstart, an alternative to sysvinit, which works completely differently.  The [Upstart CookBook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#runlevels) discusses runlevels and how to work with them.

Generally, though, the RedHat concept of runlevels isn't used on Debian or derivatives, including Ubuntu; they have only "single user" or "everything running", without any of the "network, but not graphics" style distinctions that RedHat draws.

Comment: There are 3 paradigms to manage services in Ubuntu. `System V init`, `upstart` and `systemd`. As of Ubuntu 18.04, it is `systemd`.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned Ubuntu does now use [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/).

The `/etc/inittab` and the scripts from `/etc/init.d` or `/etc/rc.d/*` have been incorporated into several scripts in the `/etc/init` directory or `/etc/event.d` (for older versions of Upstart).

Look for the item you want to modify to have a script in that directory, (serviceX) `/etc/init/serviceX.conf` and modify it accordingly. You can find the syntax and additional information online.

However, if you need to run a program that depends on SysV Upstart has a compatibility mode. Programs that still use `/etc/rc.d/*` can put scripts in there and have them still run.

As I was looking at the scripts in `/etc/init`, there was one named `rc-sysinit.conf` - and it provides the ability to parse the `/etc/inittab` and determine the default runlevel from this file should you add one.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the default-runlevel of your Ubuntu system and looking for the /etc/inittab go change it and see that Ubuntu lacks it, don't worry(!), to do so you you can create inittab file in /etc directory and write only the following line on it:

```
id:3:initdefault:
```

(you can change "3" to your intended default rullevel)